# Audio intermittently goes out of sync

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, video, music, mediaplayer

I'm experiencing playback issues with all media, streamed and local.

Whenever I play a video or listen to music, the audio will occasionally go out of sync with the playback. (A lot more of an issue with video but this also happens with general music playing.)

I'll then have to pause the media, wait about 10 seconds, and hit play again and then playback will be fine until it goes out of sync again 20 minutes later.

I've searched a lot online for this issue, and I can't really find many resources to fix the problem.  Is anyone aware of what might be causing the problem? Maybe a solution?

Hardware: Macbook Pro (mid 2014), Yosemite (10.10.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug with an equaliser app I was using, Boom 2.

They have fixed this in their latest update.

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.